# Make React-native Ui Responsive

Tags: react-native

I am bit new to react-native . I want to make my UI responsive for all type of devices , as while using "SCSS" in web development we used to make the font responsive with vw.

But the problem is we cannot use the Viewport in react-native..

Now, my designs have fonts in "dp". I was searching for the solution for responsive.
So they have answered that we can use `PixelRatio` to get "dpi" ratio.
 and we can calculate the pixels using this formula
`px = dp * PixelRatio`. 
But the problem as the dpi value increase the font-size either become too large or too small.

I want to make the UI responsive without using any library. Please , suggest me some methods to do so..
to convert the "dp" to responsive UI pixels..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps!

Credits : [Github repo](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen/blob/master/index.js)

```js
// packages
import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

// Retrieve initial screen's width
let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

// Retrieve initial screen's height
let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

/**
 * Converts provided width percentage to independent pixel (dp).
 * @param  {string} widthPercent The percentage of screen's width that UI element should cover
 *                               along with the percentage symbol (%).
 * @return {number}              The calculated dp depending on current device's screen width.
 */
const widthPercentageToDP = widthPercent => {
  // Parse string percentage input and convert it to number.
  const elemWidth = parseFloat(widthPercent);

  // Use PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel method in order to round the layout
  // size (dp) to the nearest one that correspons to an integer number of pixels.
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenWidth * elemWidth / 100);
};

/**
 * Converts provided height percentage to independent pixel (dp).
 * @param  {string} heightPercent The percentage of screen's height that UI element should cover
 *                                along with the percentage symbol (%).
 * @return {number}               The calculated dp depending on current device's screen height.
 */
const heightPercentageToDP = heightPercent => {
  // Parse string percentage input and convert it to number.
  const elemHeight = parseFloat(heightPercent);

  // Use PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel method in order to round the layout
  // size (dp) to the nearest one that correspons to an integer number of pixels.
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenHeight * elemHeight / 100);
};

/**
 * Event listener function that detects orientation change (every time it occurs) and triggers 
 * screen rerendering. It does that, by changing the state of the screen where the function is
 * called. State changing occurs for a new state variable with the name 'orientation' that will
 * always hold the current value of the orientation after the 1st orientation change.
 * Invoke it inside the screen's constructor or in componentDidMount lifecycle method.
 * @param {object} that Screen's class component this variable. The function needs it to
 *                      invoke setState method and trigger screen rerender (this.setState()).
 */
const listenOrientationChange = that => {
  Dimensions.addEventListener('change', newDimensions => {
    // Retrieve and save new dimensions
    screenWidth = newDimensions.window.width;
    screenHeight = newDimensions.window.height;

    // Trigger screen's rerender with a state update of the orientation variable
    that.setState({
      orientation: screenWidth < screenHeight ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
    });
  });
};

/**
 * Wrapper function that removes orientation change listener and should be invoked in
 * componentWillUnmount lifecycle method of every class component (UI screen) that
 * listenOrientationChange function has been invoked. This should be done in order to
 * avoid adding new listeners every time the same component is re-mounted.
 */
const removeOrientationListener = () => {
  Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', () => {});
};

export {
  widthPercentageToDP,
  heightPercentageToDP,
  listenOrientationChange,
  removeOrientationListener
};


//In your component
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from '../resposive-helper';

//Styles
shadowOffset: { width: wp(1), height: hp(1) },
borderRadius: wp(50),
paddingTop: hp(1.5),
paddingBottom: hp(1.5),
paddingLeft: wp(2.5),
paddingRight: wp(2.5),
```

Comment: The above code is also available in [this Github repo](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen/blob/master/index.js) that I ran across. Let's give credit to that author.

Comment: For listenOrientationChange . What should be that parameter in functional component ?

Answer (score 0):

use this function for text normalization

```
const normalize = (size) => {
  if (pixelRatio >= 2 && pixelRatio < 3) {
    // iphone 5s and older Androids
    if (deviceWidth < 360) {
      return size * 0.95;
    }

    // iphone 5
    if (deviceHeight < 667) {
      return size;
      // iphone 6-6s
    }

    if (deviceHeight >= 667 && deviceHeight <= 735) {
      return size * 1.15;
    }
    // older phablets
    return size * 1.25;
  }

  if (pixelRatio >= 3 && pixelRatio < 3.5) {
    // catch Android font scaling on small machines
    // where pixel ratio / font scale ratio => 3:3
    if (deviceWidth <= 360) {
      return size;
    }

    // Catch other weird android width sizings
    if (deviceHeight < 667) {
      return size * 1.15;
      // catch in-between size Androids and scale font up
      // a tad but not too much
    }

    if (deviceHeight >= 667 && deviceHeight <= 735) {
      return size * 1.2;
    }

    // catch larger devices
    // ie iphone 6s plus / 7 plus / mi note 等等
    return size * 1.27;
  }

  if (pixelRatio >= 3.5) {
    // catch Android font scaling on small machines
    // where pixel ratio / font scale ratio => 3:3
    if (deviceWidth <= 360) {
      return size;
      // Catch other smaller android height sizings
    }

    if (deviceHeight < 667) {
      return size * 1.2;
      // catch in-between size Androids and scale font up
      // a tad but not too much
    }

    if (deviceHeight >= 667 && deviceHeight <= 735) {
      return size * 1.25;
    }

    // catch larger phablet devices
    return size * 1.4;
  }

  return size;
};
```

I have use this in my opensource [project](https://github.com/bytefuge/Anime-jisho/blob/master/src/widget/Text/normalize.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this docs: [see here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio)

PixelRatio
PixelRatio gives you access to the device's pixel density and font scale.

Fetching a correctly sized image
You should get a higher resolution image if you are on a high pixel density device. A good rule of thumb is to multiply the size of the image you display by the pixel ratio.

```
const image = getImage({
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100),
});
<Image source={image} style={{width: 200, height: 100}} />;
```