# React Native app with same code but different result in iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, styling

I am new with React and I am taking a course in Udemy about React Native.
I came across with a styling issue which using same code and StyleSheet property, the borderWith in a Text, it looks different in Android and iOS.

When I was adding a thick "borderWith" to my Text component, in iOS the text it takes a bit of margin automatically from the border but Android mixes the border with the Text.
I saw a solution that it is using the Platform module or file extension but I would like to know if I could avoid this case and have most of my code similar to both devices.

```
const BoxScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Box screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyle: {
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: 'black',
    },
    textStyle: {
        borderWidth: 10,
        borderColor: 'red',
        // marginVertical: 20,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
    }
});
```

Result in iOS:

[image: Result in iOS]

Result in Android:

[image: Result in Android]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting I've never noticed it before.
that is because of margin!
in **ios** total height and width of an element calculated as the sum of the border, padding, and element inner height so if you give it a margin it pushes border and padding it's like the border is growing to **outside** of the box.
in **Android** outer height is rendered as the inner height. it's like border growing **inside** the box.
so to fix this you should justify the text in the center of the box to achieve the desired result in both platforms:

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return(
        <View style={styles.box}>
          <Text style={styles.title}> Box Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles={
  title : {
    flex : 1,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    borderWidth : 10,
    borderColor : 'red',
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20,
  },
  box : {
    borderWidth : 3,
    borderColor : 'black',
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works, although in iPhone the text is on the bottom but it is great to know the explanation about why this is happening and by this way at least I can design, really appreciate.
Do you know where I can find more information about these details between iOS and Android?

Comment: @HouseinAsadi I posted a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875092/why-is-this-react-native-screen-different-on-android-and-ios?noredirect=1#comment109455426_61875092, if you can, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Try this,

   issue regarding android then you can use Platform.OS ,

   more information to visit,
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code

```
   const BoxScreen = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Box screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        viewStyle: {
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: 'black',
        },
        textStyle: {
            borderWidth: 10,
            borderColor: 'red',
            // marginVertical: 20,
            marginHorizontal: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 30,
            padding:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 5

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Dixit, but the idea of the post was to try to look for another way a part of the Platform, but in whatever case I appreciate your example.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works!

```js
const BoxScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <View style={styles.textStyle}>
                <Text>Box screen</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyle: {
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: 'black',
    },
    textStyle: {
        borderWidth: 10,
        borderColor: 'red',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    }
});
```

Recommending to use responsive styles, check here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587062/make-react-native-ui-responsive/57590633#57590633)

Comment: It does not work, but thank you for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin on your text element, use padding on your view element.

In general you use margins to space between siblings, you use padding to space parents and children.

Comment: Thank you very much about that info but in this case, the problem is inside the text, as you can see, in my text I have a border defined and the content of my text mixes with this border, so the View does not have anything to do here I think.

Comment: @AlonBarDavid I have posted a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875092/why-is-this-react-native-screen-different-on-android-and-ios?noredirect=1#comment109455426_61875092, if you can, please take a look.

Comment: You get this behavior even if the margin and border are on the containing <View> and there's no styling on the <Text>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in text style

```
 textAlign: 'center'
```

Comment: How is this a solution, or even close to what is being asked?